# Making a module proprietary

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The paper on ROS (ROS: an open-source Robot Operating System) mentions the following:

*"As such, systems built around ROS can use ﬁne-grain licensing of their various components: individual modules can incorporate software protected by various licenses ranging from GPL to BSD to proprietary, but license “contamination” ends at the module boundary"*

Can I have more information on this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69652/making-a-module-proprietary/) by [RP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5635/rp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2013-09-06**:
I too would be interested in finding more information on this. Thank you for posting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are writing a module you can keep it proprietary by not releasing its source.  Note you do need to comply with any licenses of code with which you integrate.

Much of the ROS ecosystem is released under BSD or Apache 2 both of which are very permissive licenses.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1